# What is the correct way of defining a differentiable function with scalar arguments that returns a vector/array?

Tags: swift, automatic-differentiation

I am a beginner in Swift and am testing its AD capabilities. I have the following function

```swift
import Foundation
import _Differentiation

@differentiable(reverse)
func numToVec1(_ x: Float) -> Array<Float>.DifferentiableView {
    typealias V = Array<Float>
    return V.DifferentiableView([sin(x), cos(x), x*x])
}
```

And going by the [stdlib source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4c80ae34f5c3f76a9fab1b0a8901b80abd745fb4/stdlib/public/Differentiation/DifferentialOperators.swift#L122), the derivative of this function is calculated using `derivative(at:of:)`

```swift
let scalarInput: Float = 42.0 
let dnv1 = derivative(at: scalarInput, of: numToVec1)
```

This compiles, but results in the following runtime error.

```
_Differentiation/DifferentiationUtilities.swift:40: Fatal error: JVP does not exist. Use '-Xfrontend -enable-experimental-forward-mode-differentiation' to enable differential-first differentiation APIs.
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f4107c1aa60 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile + 112
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f410790d3af <unavailable> + 1442735
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f410790d1c7 <unavailable> + 1442247
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f410790bfd0 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 364
4    libswift_Differentiation.so        0x00007f410805d464 <unavailable> + 169060
5    output.s                           0x000055abacce9189 <unavailable> + 8585
6    output.s                           0x000055abacce8e37 <unavailable> + 7735
7    libswift_Differentiation.so        0x00007f410805b820 valueWithDifferential<A, B>(at:of:) + 106
8    libswift_Differentiation.so        0x00007f410805bca0 differential<A, B>(at:of:) + 93
9    libswift_Differentiation.so        0x00007f410805c050 derivative<A, B>(at:of:) + 89
10   output.s                           0x000055abacce8c09 <unavailable> + 7177
11   libc.so.6                          0x00007f410759df90 __libc_start_main + 243
12   output.s                           0x000055abacce87fe <unavailable> + 6142
Program terminated with signal: SIGILL
```

And compiling with the recommended flags results in a compile-time error.

```
Assertion failed: it != bufferMap.end() && "Tangent buffer should already exist", file D:\a\1\s\swift\lib\SILOptimizer\Differentiation\JVPCloner.cpp, line 317
Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
...
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyaglAdwI0i5FY1RECQ6s0wBhdPQCubJiACssi4AMgRM2ABy3gBG2KRSPOQADuhKxI5M7l4%2BBsmpDkIhYZFsMXE8WjbYdvlMIkQspESZ3r4BldXpdQ1EhRHRsfE29Y3N2QlKwz2hfSUD5QCUNuiepKicXARsyY0A1AD6ACKWNLHMDiw1AKRaAIKb20Q7AGLLTJgX6dc3XwAChDQnUhnAgsKKMCBAgBusRU8y%2BNE8TFQOyY3gAKugAGrYVA8CB7HaaZ70dAXeY7AC0lwAzLgdjdSKQWABPGmuJ4ki403AAOiOANOwhBYOwmII2DMO0uAHYAEJfHaKnZEZmJbASEFKHaYqXUg70xkstkc0lEbkKpVAogrJjavnHQXnEViiUQS5%2BWWpJgQdSLHYYJQ%2Bv3qABU6ndBzhtxlBy%2BX0YjyU4iMpAAkkxEp4iCBiabdfrpAAmHlaKW3BM7TBMSE8fOV2IESEfaEQC45pMSBrpzPWHboGg51FsDHY3FRm6JUihIgQKs1%2BZcRb0bh%2Bfi%2BLg6cjobgiCxWHZKZarbBSwvUvjkbMbxeLJDqnBxCCLADWIGp1J576/35/ADZDNw0j8GwIDSNKPJntIv7SgAHL%2BhbSDBPDnv%2B66btuXD8EoIAVFeOiLHAsAoBgWwMLElDUCRiRkXE5iWEQfgweQOCQgQawumYADyarrhedD0EQMLUFE2j8FEoQNMy3AXuJrCkMynFRLoOJXheJEcMInFMPQUnXsx2BRJ4wCuBI9DYbw/A4GwxjAJIemEEC9iNtg5mbtg6g4lm6ybtOVSiYYBBREy8nuDg/lEFOIEWYsNBGMASgcdxzDSfwgjCGIEicDIcjCMoaiaHp%2BgJEYJggHRVgBVE2GQIs6CJDU5n8Og0KMgQODVU%2B7QqekzhvKMvgJME0zFKUOQpGkQj9WNeTpL0I1zF1TlCF0IweC0Bi2N1y2THN/RlEM3RTeMO3DXtUiLIeKxrOdAFcKu5BoU13CEnBFK/tIB57kQyJ%2BDyME7BA%2BDEGQp7ngul6iQRKDLEQPYURAVE0eE7DrOor3vZ99E/X9/DYIQJBTpgBhpaIyZZbIJN5Ro/lFeQZhMokKVLiua7%2BRhnFZj2fY0C9v5vR95XfTsv3/RA7ikYwpCgzw4N4Te5B3iwD7UMzXBAeQIF%2BMW0q/n41KFsh0p%2BDwcEwbIj1btwWEGHL8wvv4FTLlw1Ks3pGH8Lb5CEQg8AQMRWB4PjZDw/xzAoylOWk5lUgU/IVMFZu%2BiFoYNllV9i01L1bhrWM5BDUUZ3lEk401EdxczQUp2zGUFSbUttSTGXdc1CtUwF9XUi143OcDQdjS7R3CxLFd6z3GQjwvIi7xXLcY%2B7IcDpAkKHxCHGtx/IvwKguCUIwtg44IkiKLoliOJ4gSRImmSlLcgaTKstS7KcmatL2gKS9OowHFSnKFqKiqaoNQsC1DqGk%2BoGT32NM/c0twlQ7CtDaO0/JARb2dOKMwboPReiDOQf0KQcGEjDBGccMY143EXLde6FsMK7nogeI8axQaFg9pDe2fhHaAWAg7B6bMrY2BwhDa8BFEB%2BzQOgCW5EqAI3EdRSWad6KMX0qxdi6Ckq8VSgwQSpBsIQBEnpWSkkI4GPkopZS9gI7qTOFpHS/kcCGWMqZcyF4rI2TspuBy3VoSuVxh5VAXkI6%2BSdpueggVgrMlCt5D2kUmYCDiglVRPEI4kwypIbKlMVDU0KiAZOJVTDpxCVVeAtV6rpHMhSAAGjQUg8gXCUjDiKCk7k1SRTOBICkghSBmAaJgCkbAA4Un%2BCg5eNQmotUJi5IpGceoQBcGXfOMxRoJFyBNDIPdporIHosqZ21DprPGFULaDduibIWhMXZWRe5nP7lXRZF0GGcELKrKhvCuC835pjKw2NRZAwJkw2WkMvbQ05lmeGiNJbIw4NwNGfMMaCy%2BbjIOhNsmRxSeTSO8cabIvpiwRm0VKGu3QtwDmsMszczebCr6XyAbi1kbEP5LChG3nvAMTqTt1aawqNQvh2EEi2zYRw52BKnqYUEfhVWzCeFuz4Xy8gLVUhOGkEAA%3D%3D%3D) is a Godbolt link showcasing this problem.
So, before opening an issue I would like to confirm whether I am doing this the intended way or not.